# SQL Server: Coordinate conversion from NZTM to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, latitude-longitude

I got a table that has shape value in one of the columns. I am converting shape value into geo_json formate and calculating centroid value and saving in two columns. The coordinate system of shape value is NZTM 2000 and I am trying to convert into WGS84. Then I am calculating Lat and long using centriod value. Below is my code:

```
;with Parcel_shape as (
Select *, geometry::STGeomFromText ([shape].STAsText() , 4326 ).ToString() geo_json, 
geometry::STGeomFromText ([shape].STCentroid().STAsText(), 4326 ) centroid from parcel
)
Select *, centroid.STY as lat, centroid.STX as long, centroid.STSrid as coord_sys from Parcel_Shape
```

I am attaching the sample of the output:

[image]

As you can see that lat and long columns are not converted into WGS84 coordinate system. I was expecting lat and long into formate such as lat value in negative such as (lat -41.33105 and long 174.77428, I made up value). Could anyone help me where I am making the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are lying to the database:

```
Select *, geometry::STGeomFromText ([shape].STAsText() , 4326 ).ToString()
```

tells it that it's importing a geometry in lon/lat (4326) from some text. From the text I can see in your image those text geometries are in NZTM coordinates, so you need to create the geometries in that projection and then **reproject** them into WGS84.